# Project Robot from Eloquent javascript chapter 7

Tags: javascript

I have tried understanding the output of the code below but I can't wrap my head around it. It returns `["Bob's House", "Town Hall"]`. 
Why doesn't it include `"Alice's House"` in the array?

```js
const roads = [
  "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
  "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
  "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
  "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
  "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
  "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"
];

function buildGraph(edges) {
  let graph = Object.create(null);

  function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (graph[from] == null)
      graph[from] = [to];
    else
      graph[from].push(to);
  }

  for (let [from, to] of edges.map(item => item.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }
  return graph;
}

const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);

console.log(roadGraph);

function findRoute(graph, from, to) {
  let work = [{
    at: from,
    route: []
  }];

  for (let i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
    let {
      at,
      route
    } = work[i];
    for (let place of graph[at]) {
      if (place == to) return route.concat(place);
      if (!work.some(w => w.at == place))
        work.push({
          at: place,
          route: route.concat(place)
        });
    }
  }

}

console.log(findRoute(roadGraph, "Alice's House", "Town Hall"));
```

Comment: I have added a console.log of the roadgraph - you can see there is only Bob's house between Alice  and Town hall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with `from` in `route`:

```
let work = [{
  at: from,
  route: [from]
}];
```

Comment: @AbdulrasheedAgunbiade if you find the answer valuable, consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers